# column "distance" does not exist

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando correr una query que encuentra los lugares cercanos a mi locacion, pero cada vez que la intento correr me retorna el siguiente error:
`column "distance" does not exist`
Si saco distance y solo dejo hasta el `FROM posts` me retorna el id del post y una columna `distance`.

Pero si lo dejo de la forma original, me retorna el error.

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-32.63) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-71.42) ) + sin( radians(-32.63) ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM posts HAVING
distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: Que motor de sql estás usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso esta pasando porque columnas con alias pueden ser usadas en un order by pero no pueden ser evaluadas por un where, group by o having
puedes verlo en la documentacion de sql server [sql server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173451.aspx)

Una posible solucion puede ser esta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT 
      id, 
      ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-32.63) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
      cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-71.42) ) + sin( radians(-32.63) ) * 
      sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM posts 
  ORDER BY distance ) as TempPost
WHERE distance < 25
```

Ten cuidado porque este codigo asi se vuelve un poco mas complicado de leer

Comment: Gracias, pablo me funciono perfectamente.